# How to echo out decrypt data in PHP

Tags: php, encryption

First, i have use `aes_encrypt` to encrypt the password

[image]

Then i have use `aes_decrypt` to decrypt the password

[image]

The issue is when i try to echo out the data in a table using 
`<?php echo $row['pass'];?>`,  there'll be an error

> "Undefined index: pass in"

SQL insert

> insert into username (userName,pass) values('$userName',
>   aes_encrypt('$pass','k'))

SQL select

> SELECT UserNameID,userName,aes_decrypt(pass,'k') from username

What went wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: Could you show us the sql query. I suspect there is no "pass" alias in it. (eg. aes_decrypt(pass, 'k') AS pass.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.   Instead  use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions with about a 100ms duration. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: With PHP use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), the pair are secure and easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to use an alias here?

```
SELECT aes_decrypt(pass, 'k') AS pass_decrypted FROM ...
```

And then access it with

```
echo $row['pass_decrypted'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your result set is the password column named as used function. All you need is to set an alias of that column such as: `aes_decrypt(pass,'k') as 'pass'`:

```
SELECT UserNameID, userName, aes_decrypt(pass,'k') as pass FROM username
```

Your PHP code expect the column 'pass' in result set..